# Confused creating json using for loop

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a json by looping over the data that I got and here the problem is I'm able to get the values correctly, but coming to the keys, they are not getting populated as expected. Here is my code.

```
var item = [{
    "max": "0.575",
  "ingredients": "a",
}, {
   "max": "10.25",
  "ingredients": "b"
}, {
   "max": "98.5",
   "ingredients": "c",
 }];

var valuesForChart = {
  data: []
};

item.forEach(function(subItem) {
  var names = subItem.ingredients;
  var level = subItem.max;
  valuesForChart.data.push({
    names: level
  });
});

document.getElementById("x").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(valuesForChart);
```

Here `item` is returned from my database. when I run this, I get the output as below.

```
{"data":[{"names":"0.575"},{"names":"10.25"},{"names":"98.5"}]}
```

but my expected output is

```
{"data":[{"a":"0.575"},{"b":"10.25"},{"c":"98.5"}]}
```

very confused on where I'm going wrong. please let me know on how can I fix this.

Here is a working fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/j8gj9uv0/2/

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to evaluate the `names` using `[names]`

When you use `[]` notation at the property declaration in the object, it gets an expression and sets *the value of that expression* as the property name. So the name is not just `names` but what under the `names`.

```js
var item = [
    { "max": "0.575", "ingredients": "a" }, 
    { "max": "10.25", "ingredients": "b" }, 
    { "max": "98.5", "ingredients": "c" }
];

var valuesForChart = {
  data: []
};

item.forEach(function(subItem) {
  var names = subItem.ingredients;
  var level = subItem.max;
  valuesForChart.data.push({
    [names]: level
  });
});

console.log(valuesForChart);
```

Comment: Thanks Suren this is working as expected, can you please shower some light on what's happening here?

Comment: @user3872094 Updated